# how to run windows service as admin

Tags: c#, windows-services

in my windows service i can not create file in `onStart` method give me an error

**error In onstart method Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\xxx\BridgeServiceLog.txt' is denied.**

now how i can run my service as admin by code

Comment: Why are you trying to store your files in the Windows directory? They don't belong there!

Answer (score 1):

You can't elevate your own process. Additionally, since a service isn't intended to interact with the desktop a user wouldn't be shown any notices you prompt. You would need to adjust the user account your service is executed under.

[image]